# Find text in top level <li> only and apply class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying for over 2 hours to solve this and it's driving me insane (jQuery newbie - sorry).

```
<ul>
    <li>Dog
        <ul>
            <li>Another Dog</li>
            <li>Another Cat</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Cat
        <ul>
            <li>I like animals
                <ul>
                    <li>More Dog</li>
                    <li>A Mouse</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is look for the word "Cat" but only in the top level LI's (ignoring children) and apply a css class to the top level LI.

So for example:

```
$('ul li:contains("Cat")').addClass('foo');
```

would apply the foo class to both top level LI's when I only want it to be applied to the second top LI (the one with Cat text on the top level).

Note: This is a small list example. There could be 20+ top level LI's with 4 or more nested UL's under each one; all capable of having the word Cat so needs to be robust enough to handle an expansive nested structure. Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The root parent needs to be identified by the attribute, add a class to it.

```
<ul class="root">
```

Use **[`>`- child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)** to find immediate/direct child.

> Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

```
$('ul.root > li').filter(function(){
    return this.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim() === "Cat"
    //This would select text nodes with exact match to Cat.
    //For text containing cat use, return this.childNodes[0].nodeValue.indexOf("Cat")> -1
})
```

`$('ul:not(ul ul) > li').filter...` seems a better approach as [suggested by Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851573/jquery-find-text-in-top-level-li-only-and-apply-class/30851621?noredirect=1#comment49747859_30851621)

You could still do

```
$('ul > li:contains("Cat")')
```

But `:contains()` would still search for `Cat` in children and not just the actual `li`.

Comment: Adding a class to the root `ul` helps, but it's not required:  `$('ul:not(ul ul) > li')` would do it.

Comment: Yes. This seems a better solution!

Comment: @RickHitchcock I hadn't thought of using :not selectors like that before, that's much cleaner than my answer. I should brush up on my CSS sometime.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a bit more vanilla JavaScript with your jQuery, you could do something like this without having to add any classes to your existing HTML:

```
$('ul > li').filter(function (i, e) {
    return (/cat/i).test(e.firstChild.textContent) &&
        (!e.parentNode.parentNode || e.parentNode.parentNode.tagName !== 'LI');
}).addClass('foo');
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/m5x2jadz/3/)

This code assumes that your HTML structure is like what you posted: each list item has text at the start, which is optionally followed by an unordered list.

It finds all list items inside of unordered lists, then filters by those with the first element's content (assumed to be a text node) containing "cat", and then checks to see if its parent's parent doesn't exist (this check mostly for the fiddle, it would probably always exist in practice) or isn't a list item.

If you want the "cat" check to be case-sensitive, change the regular expression to `/Cat/` instead of `/cat/i`.

Answer (score 0):

**Iteration 1**

Update your code to

```
$('ul > li:contains("Cat")').addClass('foo');
```

**Iteration 2**

This will make sure that only the first level children will be checked.

However, it has a problem. As there many ul - li elements in your html.

So you need to add class or id.

So update your html, with adding id/class to first level ul

```
<ul class="first_list">
```

And, now further update your JS to

```
 $('ul.first_list > li:contains("Cat")').addClass('foo');
```

**Iteration 3**

Now, li:contains will check for text Cat in li and its children. We need to fix that with the following.

Now, how to get the text of only the element ignoring text of children.

Well, it is not straightforward. You need to update your code a bit for this.

```
$('ul.first_list > li).each(function(){
    var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    if(text.indexOf("Cat") !== -1){
        $(this).addClass('foo');
    }
});
```

Comment: `:contains()` check for the text content, unregarding any child level

Comment: It seems like you still don't get what ``:contains()`` does.

Comment: Dasesin - Can you explain your statement?